# Metro style windows 7 WPF app -toggleSwitch-

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro

I'm currently fiddling around with the look of one of my older wpf apps using [MahApps](http://mahapps.com/MahApps.Metro/#icons) metro library. I'm stuck with **Controls:ToggleSwitch** where I can bind almost everything but commands.
When I try to bind a command as below,

```
<Controls:ToggleSwitch Header="Start Playing" OnLabel="Stop" OffLabel="Play" 
    IsChecked="{Binding ToggleRecordCommand}"
    CommandParameter="{Binding}"  />
```

I get an error like;

```
Error   62  A TwoWay or OneWayToSource binding cannot work on the read-only property 'ToggleRecordCommand' of type 'RecorderApp.View.MainWindowViewModel'.
```

Also it tells me there is no **CommandParameter**. How am I going to bind actions to this?

Comment: in order to use CommandParameter you must specify Command whick i think will be raised on Clicked event not on IsChecked boolean property

Comment: Normally, I can bind commands to buttons. But is it not possible with toggle switch? I had planned to handle all action in the view model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, as Brendan said, IsChecked property has to be binded with a general Property which has INotifyPropertyChanged, NOT an ICommand type.

In order to bind with Command, the easiest workaround is to use `Click`(or `Checked`) event with xaml.cs Code-behind works.

In XAML, as below.

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="recordButton" 
Checked="OnRecordButton_Checked" 
IsChecked={Binding IsRecording} />
```

In Code-behind, as below.

```
private void OnRecordButton_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (recordButton.IsChecked.GetValueOrDefault())
    {
        // Do your own logic to execute command. with-or-without command parameter.
        viewModel.ToggleRecordCommand.Execute(null);
    }
}
```

And, In ViewModel (assumption), as below.

```
// Property for toggle button GUI update
public bool IsRecording{
get{ return _isRecording;}
set{
    _isRecording = value;
    NotifyPropertyChanged("IsRecording");
    }
}

public ICommand ToggleRecordCommand{
// Your command logic.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`IsChecked` is a `bool?` property and will likely not work if you pass it an ICommand. [Source code](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/master/MahApps.Metro/Controls/ToggleSwitch.cs#L77)

If you'd like to see this supported, please raise an issue on the [project site](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro) and we can discuss it further.